# Erro 5: Acesso negado na tentativa de instalar um serviço criado no Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, instalador, services

Criei um aplicado de serviços e depois da instalação do mesmo, não consigo inicia-lo aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Mensagem de Erro]

1. Já verifiquei permissões do aplicativo;
2. Já tentei apagar "logs";
3. Já reiniciei o servidor;
4. já desinstalei e re-instalei o serviço acessando `prompt` do DOS como Administrador

Alguém teria uma ideia do que pode estar causando isso?

**PS: Sistema operacional Windows Server 2012 Standard**

Answer (score -1):

Você pode estar tendo problemas com as permissões de [acessos a diretórios](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5119.instalacao-do-active-directory-no-windows-server-2012-pt-br.aspx) ou [bloqueio do firewall](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc772589%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), por não ter declarados as regras necessárias.

Comment: tal resposta cabe mais como um comentário, além do PA ter informado que já verificou as permissões.